# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jndiDataSource

Tags: java

I imported a project and try to run on a server without making any changes, I get the below exception. Can any body please help me what can be the problem

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jndiDataSource
        at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.getObjectFromBindings(RefFSContext.java:400)
        at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookupObject(RefFSContext.java:327)
        at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
        at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.ssc.lsf.common.pool.ConnectionPool.createDatasource(ConnectionPool.java:85)
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context? Like: what kind of project is it, and maybe some of it's configuration and what server you want to run this on?

Answer (score 0):

The project you have imported seems to make use of `DataSource` configured using JNDI. The code looks up for the datasource in the name 'jndiDataSource'. Please ensure that the datasource is properly configured. Hope this gives an idea